# Route to another component and page when click on an image reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**Expected:** when clicking on the image from one component(PhotosList), it routes to another page with the specified url to view the other component(Image details)

**Reality:** what happens that when clicking on the image, both components are rendered on the same page but with the different url.

using import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

Here's the return of the functional component(PhotosList)

```
 return (
    <Router>
      <div className="layout">
        <Masonry gutter={"5 px"} columnsCount={3}>
          {photosList.map((photo: any) => (
            <Link to={"/details"}>
              <img src={photo.download_url} />
            </Link>
          ))}
        </Masonry>

        <button onClick={loadMore} className="btn-grad">
          {isLoading ? "Loading..." : "Load More"}
        </button>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={"/details"} component={ImageDetails}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

and the app file is

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>Album</header>
      <PhotosList />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you tried using NavLink instead of Link? Link is intended for redirecting the user outside of your app. NavLink is meant for all navigation within the app.

Comment: I just realized that whenever you redirect to '/details', the current component (which spawns the /details route) will be unmounted. Instead move this route inside of the root router. This should not be done this way. I prefer to have my router at the top level which is why i'd never get this kind of error. I have heard of route splitting before, i havent used it however. I am pretty sure it is not done this way though.

Comment: @DimitarDev I didn't find that difference between navlink and link in the documentation. I tried to put router at the root but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
return (
      <div className="layout">
        <Masonry gutter={"5 px"} columnsCount={3}>
          {photosList.map((photo: any) => (
            <Link to={"/details"}>
              <img src={photo.download_url} />
            </Link>
          ))}
        </Masonry>

        <button onClick={loadMore} className="btn-grad">
          {isLoading ? "Loading..." : "Load More"}
        </button>
      </div>
  );
```

and in the app file

```
const App = () => {
  return (
   <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <header>Album</header>
      <PhotosList />
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path={"/photilist"} component={PhotosList}></Route>
          <Route exact path={"/details"} component={ImageDetails}></Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>
   </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, you have rendered the `PhotoList` component which then renders a list of photos each with a link to `/details`.

In the same component you set up the `/details` route.

Whenever you click the `Link` which redirects to `/details`, the `PhotoList` component will (should) unmount. Once this component is unmounted, so is the `Route` which sets up the component which should be rendered on `/details` route. So you are on `/details` but the router has no idea what component should be rendered because the following code:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={"/details"} component={ImageDetails}></Route>
</Switch>
```

no longer exists.

To avoid this, don't put `Routes` this far down in your application. Routes should always be close to the top level (children/grandchildren of Router). This makes projects way easier to manage. I do have projects with upwards of 100 routes and I do split up my routes into seperate files (for example each module will have a ModuleRoutes.js file in which I set up the routes for that module), then you can create a `RootRouter` components which renders these seperate JS files (Which are really React components) and you render the `RootRouter` inside of your `<BrowserRouter>` / `<Router>`.

You can abstract this even higher by creating an array of objects which hold details about each route (route name, path, component for the route, function / data you want to pass down to the component, access control (true/false) defined as a logical expression of your choosing - i.e. `user.isLoggedIn === true`). By employing this abstraction you minimize the room for error because errors and bugs are much easier to spot when they are in this kind of form (object) as opposed to JSx which takes up more lines of code, has messy indentation and is not very clean in general.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your clear explanation!!